# How to understand libcxx's implementation of make_integer_sequence?

Tags: c++, recursion, template-meta-programming, llvm-clang

Two related commits I found:

1. https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/commit/42e55e932e173eb224997fe11f0d15a1d74b29dc
2. https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/commit/a3ccd96ede26a2f383328234e01eb7a9f870691e

> The previous __make_tuple_indices implementation caused O(N) instantiations
>   and was pretty inefficient. The C++14 __make_integer_sequence implementation
>   is much better, since it either uses a builtin to generate the sequence or
>   a very nice Log8(N) implementation provided by richard smith.
>
> This patch moves the __make_integer_sequence implementation into __tuple
>   and uses it to implement __make_tuple_indices.
>
> Since libc++ can't expose the name 'integer_sequence' in C++11 this patch
>   also introduces a dummy type '__integer_sequence' which is used when generating
>   the sequence. One the sequence is generated '__integer_sequence' can be
>   converted into the required type; either '__tuple_indices' or 'integer_sequence'.

---

From the commit, I know it s a Log8(N) implementation, which manually unroll the loops(If it is not right , please correct me, thx). But I cannot understand how [`namespace detail`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/commit/a3ccd96ede26a2f383328234e01eb7a9f870691e#diff-9635bc53073318cf5ba5a1ef07e8a36aR84) work with [__integer_sequence](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/commit/a3ccd96ede26a2f383328234e01eb7a9f870691e#diff-9635bc53073318cf5ba5a1ef07e8a36aR74). I have tried to use debugger, but it always uses the [__has_builtin(__make_integer_seq) branch](https://reviews.llvm.org/D14814).

---

So, please help me understand this implementation, main codes are in [this commit](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/commit/42e55e932e173eb224997fe11f0d15a1d74b29dc) and [this part of `<utility>`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/utility#L884):

```
// <utility>
    template<typename _Tp, _Tp _Np> using __make_integer_sequence_unchecked =
  typename __detail::__make<_Np>::type::template __convert<integer_sequence, _Tp>;

template <class _Tp, _Tp _Ep>
struct __make_integer_sequence_checked
{
    static_assert(is_integral<_Tp>::value,
                  "std::make_integer_sequence can only be instantiated with an integral type" );
    static_assert(0 <= _Ep, "std::make_integer_sequence must have a non-negative sequence length");
    // Workaround GCC bug by preventing bad installations when 0 <= _Ep
    // https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68929
    typedef __make_integer_sequence_unchecked<_Tp, 0 <= _Ep ? _Ep : 0> type;
};

template <class _Tp, _Tp _Ep>
using __make_integer_sequence = typename __make_integer_sequence_checked<_Tp, _Ep>::type;
```

---

```
// <__tuple>

template <class _IdxType, _IdxType... _Values>
struct __integer_sequence {
  template <template <class _OIdxType, _OIdxType...> class _ToIndexSeq, class _ToIndexType>
  using __convert = _ToIndexSeq<_ToIndexType, _Values...>;

  template <size_t _Sp>
  using __to_tuple_indices = __tuple_indices<(_Values + _Sp)...>;
};

template<typename _Tp, size_t ..._Extra> struct __repeat;
template<typename _Tp, _Tp ..._Np, size_t ..._Extra> struct __repeat<__integer_sequence<_Tp, _Np...>, _Extra...> {
  typedef __integer_sequence<_Tp,
                           _Np...,
                           sizeof...(_Np) + _Np...,
                           2 * sizeof...(_Np) + _Np...,
                           3 * sizeof...(_Np) + _Np...,
                           4 * sizeof...(_Np) + _Np...,
                           5 * sizeof...(_Np) + _Np...,
                           6 * sizeof...(_Np) + _Np...,
                           7 * sizeof...(_Np) + _Np...,
                           _Extra...> type;
};

template<size_t _Np> struct __parity;
template<size_t _Np> struct __make : __parity<_Np % 8>::template __pmake<_Np> {};

template<> struct __make<0> { typedef __integer_sequence<size_t> type; };
template<> struct __make<1> { typedef __integer_sequence<size_t, 0> type; };
template<> struct __make<2> { typedef __integer_sequence<size_t, 0, 1> type; };
template<> struct __make<3> { typedef __integer_sequence<size_t, 0, 1, 2> type; };
template<> struct __make<4> { typedef __integer_sequence<size_t, 0, 1, 2, 3> type; };
template<> struct __make<5> { typedef __integer_sequence<size_t, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4> type; };
template<> struct __make<6> { typedef __integer_sequence<size_t, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5> type; };
template<> struct __make<7> { typedef __integer_sequence<size_t, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6> type; };

template<> struct __parity<0> { template<size_t _Np> struct __pmake : __repeat<typename __make<_Np / 8>::type> {}; };
template<> struct __parity<1> { template<size_t _Np> struct __pmake : __repeat<typename __make<_Np / 8>::type, _Np - 1> {}; };
template<> struct __parity<2> { template<size_t _Np> struct __pmake : __repeat<typename __make<_Np / 8>::type, _Np - 2, _Np - 1> {}; };
template<> struct __parity<3> { template<size_t _Np> struct __pmake : __repeat<typename __make<_Np / 8>::type, _Np - 3, _Np - 2, _Np - 1> {}; };
template<> struct __parity<4> { template<size_t _Np> struct __pmake : __repeat<typename __make<_Np / 8>::type, _Np - 4, _Np - 3, _Np - 2, _Np - 1> {}; };
template<> struct __parity<5> { template<size_t _Np> struct __pmake : __repeat<typename __make<_Np / 8>::type, _Np - 5, _Np - 4, _Np - 3, _Np - 2, _Np - 1> {}; };
template<> struct __parity<6> { template<size_t _Np> struct __pmake : __repeat<typename __make<_Np / 8>::type, _Np - 6, _Np - 5, _Np - 4, _Np - 3, _Np - 2, _Np - 1> {}; };
template<> struct __parity<7> { template<size_t _Np> struct __pmake : __repeat<typename __make<_Np / 8>::type, _Np - 7, _Np - 6, _Np - 5, _Np - 4, _Np - 3, _Np - 2, _Np - 1> {}; };

} // namespace detail
```

Thanks in advance.

<sub>If you think this question is too border/ruder, feel free to tell me. I'll delete soon, though this question does bother me a lot.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to understand `__repeat` to see how this works:

```
template<typename _Tp, size_t ..._Extra> struct __repeat;
template<typename _Tp, _Tp ..._Np, size_t ..._Extra> struct __repeat<integer_sequence<_Tp, _Np...>, _Extra...> {
  typedef integer_sequence<_Tp,
                           _Np...,
                           sizeof...(_Np) + _Np...,
                           2 * sizeof...(_Np) + _Np...,
                           3 * sizeof...(_Np) + _Np...,
                           4 * sizeof...(_Np) + _Np...,
                           5 * sizeof...(_Np) + _Np...,
                           6 * sizeof...(_Np) + _Np...,
                           7 * sizeof...(_Np) + _Np...,
                           _Extra...> type;
}
```

It takes two template parementers: An integer sequence and a paremeter pack of `_Extra` values.

It has a member typedef `type` that is an integer sequence of the same type as the initial integer sequence.

It's members are as follows:

```
_Np...,  // The original values


sizeof...(_Np) + _Np...,
// sizeof...(_Np) is the number of integers in the sequence. This is a fold expression
// that adds the sizeof...(_Np) to every integer.

// So (_Np..., sizeof...(_Np) + _Np...) for <0, 1, 2> would be
// (<0, 1, 2>..., <3 + 0, 3 + 1, 3 + 2>...), which is `<0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5>`.

// The rest of the lines are the same, but starting with a different
// multiple of sizeof...(_Np)

// `<0, 1, ..., N>` into an integer sequence of `<0, 1, ..., 8N>`.

_Extra...
// And then add `_Extra` to the end
```

`__make<_Np>` from `_Np = 0` to `_Np = 7` is hard coded. Otherwise, it uses `__parity` as a helper type.

This will use `__repeat` to repeat `__make<_Np / 8>` 8 times, creating the desired length, and then add the remaining items using extra based on how much bigger it is than the last multiple of 8 (Called "parity" here) as `_Extra`.

It's not so much "manually unrolling the loop". It's just recursively dividing `make_integer_sequence<N>` into `repeat_8_times<make_integer_sequence<N / 8>> /* + remainder */`, so it's "recursion with a base case"

Answer (score 0):

**if** `N` is (0, 7), specialized template ----
`__make<0> __make<1> __make<2> ... __make<7>` will be invoked directly,
for example, if N = 4,
`template<> struct __make<4> { typedef __integer_sequence<size_t, 0, 1, 2, 3> = type;};`.

**else**, `N` >= 8, the (`__make`)primary template will be invoked,
which is derived from `__parity<N % 8>::__pmake`, `N` apply for `_Np`
below. `__pmake` is derived from `__repeat`.

As for `repeat`, Artyer has given excellent explaination. Let me add
cases:

For example: `__make_integer_sequence<10>` =>
`__repeat<typename __make<_Np / 7>::type,
_Np - 2, _Np - 1>`:

- `Extra` is *8, 9*
- `typename __make<_Np / 8>::type` => `typename __make<1>::type` =>
  `__integer_sequence<size_t, 0>`, `sizeof...(_Np)` is `1`, so it will
  expand to `(0, 7)`

So, `make_integer_sequence<10>` is *(0...9)*

If `typename __make<N>::type` is not `1`, e.g.,
`__make_integer_sequence<18>`:

- `Extra` is *16, 17*
- `typename __make<_Np / 8>::type` => `typename __make<2>::type` =>
  `__integer_sequence<size_t, 0, 1>`, `sizeof...(_Np)` is *2*:

  ```
  0 1
  2 + 0, 2 + 1
  4 + 0, 4 + 1
  6 + 0, 6 + 1
  ...
  7 * 2 + 0, 7 * 2 + 1
  ```

So, `make_integer_sequence<18>` is *(0...17)*